# MongoDb PHP Push insert value into an array of array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, push

So I have a list of multiple choice questions and I want to store, every time a user answers the same question, his answer to this question. So I want to create a document per user and his answer history per question. I made an array of questions which holds the questionId and also an array of answers ('ans' with his answers. So I wrote a basic code where I add for question 1, his first answer 'a' and now I want to update this document with answer 'b'.

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->test;
$answers = $db->answers;

$answers->insert([ 'userId' => 1, 'questions' => [[ 'questionId' => '1', 'ans' => ['a'] ]]]);
$answers->update(array('userId' => 1, 'questions.questionId' => '1'),
                 array('$push' => array('questions' => array('ans' => 'b'))));
```

The problem is that instead of adding it to the existing array, a new object is created:

```
_id:5958c3e1e87cbf643400734d
userId:1
  questions:Array
  0:Object
    questionId:"1"
    ans:Array
    0:"a"
  1:questionId
    ans:"b"
```

I know this is a very basic question, but I have searched in other questions but I cannot get the syntax to work. I think the problem lays in the fact that the correct document is found, but I cannot figure out how to add it to the existing ans array instead of created a new ans field. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution finally. I had the use the . and $ notation

$answers->update(array('userId' => 1, 'questions.questionId' => '1'),
                 array('$push' => array('questions.$.ans' => 'try2')));